# cache is not available error using web method in .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx

```
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void ProcessIT(string id)
    {
        string result = id;// "Welcome Mr. " + name + ". Your address is '" + address + "'.";

        string[] idsplit = result.Split('_');
        string Quesid = idsplit[1];
        Admin_NewPractice1 a = new Admin_NewPractice1();
        a.getid(Quesid);


        // return result;
    }

    public void getid(string Quesid)
    {
        try
        {
            //ds2.Tables.Add(dt);
            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();          

            ds2 = (DataSet)Cache["mytable"];  // this line error comes 

            int m = Convert.ToInt32(Quesid);
            if (m < ds2.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
                fetchCommonData(ds2.Tables[0].Rows[m]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I dont think just the title is enough to entice me to figure out what you want.  Could you write out the question you have as well as point to the bit of code that is causing your error?

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Also, you should get rid of that try/catch block. It is only screwing up your stack trace.

Comment: please show more code. does your class extend UI.Page ?

Comment: have you tried `HttpContext.Current.Cache`  ?

Comment: Thank sir i got solution by using   HttpContext.Current.Cache

Comment: ok, i will post it as answer, for you to accept.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are accessing the Cache in a wrong way.

Please try

```
HttpContext.Current.Cache
```

`HttpContext.Current.Cache` will give you access to the cache object whose scope is application level.

P.S:
Unfortunately you cannot access the `Cache` object in custom class.

it will throw an error like

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

```
'System.Web.Caching.Cache.Get(string)'
```

Now if your `class` inherits from `System.Web.UI.Page` it doesn't generate a compile time error but rather a run time error.

It reports something like `"Cache is not available"`.

so one of the workarounds is to use

```
 HttpContext.Current.Cache
```